# Why does the following loop keep returning me results of 0?

Tags: python, loops

So I'm trying to generate a frequency spectrum, and in order to do that I'm trying to sort my data into bins from a column, which I have appended data from, called minorallelefreq. For some reason, the code is not working because I get a value of 0 for all 5 bins.

Here's the code:

```
minprop = 0
minprop1 = 0
minprop2 = 0
minprop3 = 0
minprop4 = 0 

for x in range(1,100):

    if minorallelefreq[x] <= 0.1:
        minprop = minprop + 1 
    if minorallelefreq[x] > 0.1 and minorallelefreq[x] <= 0.2: 
        minprop1 = minprop1 + 1 
    if minorallelefreq[x] > 0.2 and minorallelefreq[x] <= 0.3: 
        minprop2 = minprop2 + 1
    if minorallelefreq[x] > 0.3 and minorallelefreq[x] <= 0.4: 
        minprop3 = minprop3 + 1
    if minorallelefreq[x] > 0.4 and minorallelefreq[x] <= 0.5:
        minprop4 = minprop4 + 1



bin1 = minprop/float(counter)
bin2 = minprop1/float(counter)
bin3 = minprop2/float(counter)
bin4 = minprop3/float(counter)
bin5 = minprop4/float(counter)  
print "Bin1 (0-0.1)=", bin1, "\t", "Bin2 (0.1-0.2)=", bin2, "\t", "Bin3 (0.2-0.3)=", bin3, "\t", "Bin4 (0.3-0.4)=", bin4, "\t", "Bin5 (0.4-0.5)=", bin5
```

**So it turned out that the reason the loops weren't working is because python wasn't reading my values (which are all decimals) as decimals. So, I had to change it to float(minorallelefreq[x]), and it worked.**

Comment: maybe the value of the "counter" variable is to high?

Comment: What's in minorallelefreq?

Comment: what does `counter` equal to? and what are the values of minprop ... minprop4 ?

Comment: Minorallelefreq contains The values in that column in the file.

Comment: Counter equals 115,000 and the values of minprop...minprop4, when I type a print statement at the end of the loop  shows up to be 0, which indicates that there`s something wrong with my loop.

Comment: Well, for one thing the last condition checks if a number is `> 0.4` and `<= 0.4` which can't be true.

Comment: why are you casting 0.1 to an `int`? This just gives you 0. If `minorallelefreq[x]` was between 0 and 0.1, none of your cases would catch it.

Comment: I'm surprised it returns anything at all. I have no clue what it does.

Comment: Should it be "for x in range(1,counter):"? Also, I'd make the selections elif rather than separate if statements. Actually, I'd pull out the first digit and use an array or dictionary, but that's a larger change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if minorallelefreq[x] <= int(0.1):
    minprop = minprop + 1 
if minorallelefreq[x] > 0.1 and minorallelefreq[x] <= 0.2: 
    minprop1 = minprop1 + 1
```

means that there will be no action taken for values > 0 and <= 0.1. What happens if you remove the `int()` call?

Also, nothing will happen for values > 0.4:

```
if minorallelefreq[x] > 0.4 and minorallelefreq[x] <= 0.4:  # never True
    minprop4 = minprop4 + 1                                 # indentation??
```

Generally, you should look into chained comparisons:

```
if 0.1 < minorallelefreq[x] <= 0.2:   # much easier to read, and faster.
    # etc.
```

Comment: Adjusted my code with all your suggestions, but still no change in outcome.

Comment: Well, the code as you posted it wouldn't even run because of that indentation error. I wouldn't be surprised if there were more errors of that kind. Maybe mixed tabs/spaces, who knows.

Comment: The indentation is fine. I'm not sure which indentation error you are referring to.

Answer (score 4):

There are several possible bugs in this code

1. int(0.1) => 0, so minprop will always be 0 unless there are negative values
2. no indentation for minprop4, and it will never be set, because the value cannot simultaneously be > 0.4 and <= 0.4
3. You assume 100 elements, and that they're all between 0 and 0.4

I would suggest that you try to automatically bucketize based on the actual values, rather than the anticipated values:

```
import collections
buckets = collections.Counter()

for value in minorallfreq:
    bucket = int(value * 10) / 10.0
    buckets[bucket] += 1
```

Comment: I have looked at the data, so I know that all the values are between 0 and 0.5 . Regarding your 2nd point, it was supposed to mean `between 4 and 5`, so I fixed that. Also fixed point 1.

Comment: have you tried printing out the values of your minprop variables prior to dividing by the counter? From what sort of context is the above code copied?

Comment: Yes, I tried printing out the minprop variables prior to the division and I get a value of zero. In fact, I also tried changing the code and made it: if minorallelefreq[x] == 0.048 (.048 is the first value in the data set), but I still get a value of 0 for minprop, so the loops aren't working properly for some reason. I'm not sure what you mean by your second question.

Comment: You have two variables here where we have to guess values, scope, etc: minorallelefreq and counter. Are they global variables from within the same script? Is this part of a function or class? What are their types?

Comment: Yes they are global variables from within the same script. Counter = 115,000 in this case and minorallelefreq are values that range from 0 to 0.5 in a txt file that I am applying this program to.